# Cookies array empty when linking from form in email (Chrome)

Tags: php, cookies

I am using cookies to track user sessions.  Everything has been working fine up til now.

I created a form in an email, which links to a page:

```
<form action='https://example.com/subscription?sub=36&cust=2' method='POST' target='_blank'>
    <input type='submit' value='Update Card Details'/>
</form>
```

Sometimes it works fine.  Other times $_COOKIES is empty, even though the cookies are still set (I have tested by reloading another page open in the browser).

If I change the code to

```
<a href='https://example.com/subscription?sub=36&cust=2'>Update Card Details</a>
```

it appears to work.

I have tried setting cookies to lax or none, but makes no difference.  This might be a Chrome specific issue, as I can't recreate on Edge.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: It's odd that it works on Edge and not Chrome as underneath they both use the same browser engine. You could use the `a href` solution and style it to look like a button instead

Comment: Instead of putting the form in the email, it's considered better to link to the web page with the form.

Comment: @Barmar - I was using the form primarily so that I would have a button to click in the email.  Are buttons in emails not recommended? Or is there a better way for email?

Comment: Use a link. You can use CSS to make it look like a button.

Comment: @JacobMulquin Yes, will use `a href` if necessary, but really want to know what is going on

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks, will do that.  Still wish I knew why my cookies didn't work though...

Comment: I think it's because the form submission is coming from the mail reader, but the cookies are stored in the browser.